# determine points into a shape polygone

Tags: r, coordinates, shapes, points

So I intend to determine which points from a set of hundreds of geographic coordinates are located into a shape polygon. I was able to convert all the coordinates (latitude and longitude ) into a SpatialPointsDataFrame and I can read and plot the shapefile in R as well. 
A graph of my shp file together with the points is:

[image]

From similar questions in stackoverflow I was trying to use the function point.in.polygon in the sp package as wel as the  the over() function.
Polygon: polygon1
Points: spdf

```
pt.in.poly <- sp::over( spdf, polygon1, fn = NULL)
```

or

```
new_shape <- point.in.poly(spdf, polygon1)
```

but in both cases the result I get is:

```
Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

If its a roblem of coordinates system how can I fix it? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to either set a correct coordinate system or transform it so that they match. See `?CRS` and `?spTransform`.

Comment: Thanks  @RomanLuštrik , I failed miserably trying to fit the coordinates. The SpatialPointsDataFrame was created with the coordinates: CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0") and the shapefile have the CRS arguments:  +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
+towgs84=0,0,0      , so they seem to be the same, then how or why should I fix them? I am really stressed with this

Comment: What makes you think they're identical? The first one has `lat_ts` set to 30, at least. Try `spTransform` or provide a reproducible example.